# Ubuntu 19.10 mess up battery life

Tags: hp, battery, tlp, 19.10

After I upgraded Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 (today), battery life on my laptop was rapidly shorten. On 19.04 with TLP on it lasted about 8h on avg. now it last 2h with TLP on and same TLP settings. Laptop is HP ProBook 450 G6 with 45 Wh Li- ion(3-cell) battery and it is old 2 weeks. What should I do? Is this becaose of new Ubuntu or? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I also have the same issue. Seems like its due to 19.10. Still waiting for the solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If battery life with 19.10 is less than 19.04, it's because of the version change.

Comment: Can I do anything about it or I just need to wait for update ?

Comment: It's so new, I can't say. That's why interim releases (non-LTS releases) are thrown out there, to catch problems not caught in the testing phase, and sometimes what's found is best solved by waiting, sometimes by stepping back.